# How do I run multiple .bat files that are in subfolders

Tags: windows-server-2012, parallel-processing

I'm new to supercomputers, I recently built an Amazon EC2 instance with 128 CPUs and Microsoft server 2012. I have one folder that has 100 subfolders, in each subfolder there is a .bat file. How do I run all 100 .bat files at the same time? Also is there a specific command that I have to use to assign each .bat file processing to one CPU, so I can run all of them at the same time ensuring fast processing (parallel processing).I apologize if I'm using the wrong terminology, as I mentioned I'm new to supercomputing and parallel processing.

Comment: something about parallel processing: there's no such thing as "at the same time". Never. The laws of physics don't allow it. Withing certain tolerances things can happen at about the same time. What are you trying to achieve? Do you wish to assign each batch file (of many) to a unique processor?

Comment: Every batch file starts a lighting simulations ( to investigate light levels in interior spaces). The way I start the batch file is double click it, this starts the simulation process by calling a simulation engine called "Radiance". So I was wondering what the easiest way is to start all 200 files instead of individually double clicking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a script to run a bunch of other scripts, you might try:

```
dir /s /b *.bat
```

This will list all the batch files in all your subdirectories. You can pipe the output of that command to a batch file, eg:

```
dir /s /b *.bat > runall.bat
```

This creates runall.bat. Edit runall.bat and use a macro to prefix each line with "start", so:

```
c:\Users\KDM\Script\go.bat
```

becomes:

```
start c:\Users\KDM\Script\go.bat
```

Executing the BAT file just created will launch each of your BAT files in a separate command prompt. Let the OS take care of fairly allocating the processors.

*I'm not sure this will completely achieve what you want, though. I have a feeling you're after something more crafty. Also, the number of processors aside, you still have the limitation that you're only running on a finite piece of hardware. I mean, you can divide 1 CPU into 128 virtual CPUs if you want, but you still only have 1 CPU.*

Comment: This is awesome, I spent like five hours yesterday to figure out how I do this and I couldn't get it to work. Thanks a bunch. How do I run a macro script to add "start" to each line?

Comment: I was able to add strat in Notepad++ using by using the find and replace dialogue box. Thanks again